# Windows 2008 R2 DNS returns same result

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

We have a really strange issue with recently installed DNS server.

No matter which request submitted, it always returns 1.1.1.1, until the whole server is restarted. Restarting only the DNS service doesn't help.

After the restart, the issue returns after some time.

Has anyone encountered this, and can recommend how to resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm - apparently a new router we added wreaked havoc in network, possibly by intercepting the DNS queries.

Removing the router sorted out this issue.

Comment: you can set your own answer as the one that solved the problem

Comment: Yep, but unfortunately not immediately - have to wait some time.

Answer (score 6):

Does it return this response for domains its authoritative for or just domains that it's recursively resolving via root hints or forwarders? If the problem is happening on recursive resolution only then I'd consider sniffing the traffic the server generates to see where it's getting these erroneous answers.

I'd be really surprised if it's returning these bogus answers for domains that it can resolve authoritatively. If it is then you've got something really, really odd happening.

Personally, I'm predicting some kind of bogosity on recursive resolution. Sniff the traffic first so that you can place blame somewhere, but my gut says you've got a server specified as a forwarded that's sending you bogus data.

Comment: You right, it only happens for external domains, resolved by forwarders. I will give it a try and see what happening, perhaps the ISP DNS servers we use are misbehaving.

Comment: I don't trust ISP DNS servers. They've screwed me over too many times.

Comment: What you using as forwarded then? Google DNS servers?

Comment: @SyRenity: Root hints FTW.